# What view should I setContentView with?

Tags: android, android-activity, android-view

I'm just trying to use an `intent` to start up a second activity and on the `onCreate` method of the second activity I'm not sure If I'm setting my `setContentView()` to the right view...

onCreate():

```
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.fragment_display_information);

    if (savedInstanceState == null) {
        getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction()
                .add(R.id.container, new PlaceholderFragment()).commit();
    }

    EditText toTestView            = null, 
             fromTestView          = null, 
             subjectTestView       = null, 
             messageTestView       = null;

    String recievedToMessage       = " ",
            recievedFromMessage    = " ",
            recievedSubjectMessage = " ", 
            recievedMessage        = " " ;

    Intent i = getIntent();
    Bundle e = i.getExtras();

    if (e != null){


        recievedToMessage = e.getString(MainActivity.TO_MESSAGE);
        recievedFromMessage = e.getString(MainActivity.FROM_MESSAGE);
        recievedSubjectMessage = e.getString(MainActivity.SUBJECT_MESSAGE);
        recievedMessage = e.getString(MainActivity.MESSAGE);

        //setContentView(R.layout.activity_display_information);

        toTestView =  (EditText) findViewById(R.id.recievedToText);
        fromTestView = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.recievedFromText);
        subjectTestView = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.recievedSubjectText);
        messageTestView = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.recievedMessageText);

        toTestView.setText("To: " + recievedToMessage);
        fromTestView.setText("From: " + recievedFromMessage);
        subjectTestView.setText("Subject: " + recievedSubjectMessage);
        messageTestView.setText(recievedMessage);
    }

}
```

I have 2 second activity xmls, `fragment_display_information.xml` and `activity_display_information.xml` As of now when I try to get to the second page of my app I get an `Unortunately 'Appname' has stopped working.` Message, and in the LogCat I get a `AndroidRuntime Error` saying `View could not be found`

LogCat:

```
06-17 07:59:03.020: E/AndroidRuntime(1216): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
06-17 07:59:03.020: E/AndroidRuntime(1216): Process:  com.example.multipledatathroughactivitypractice, PID: 1216
06-17 07:59:03.020: E/AndroidRuntime(1216): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.example.multipledatathroughactivitypractice/com.example.multipledatathroughactivitypractice.DisplayInformation}: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: No view found for id 0x7f050040 (com.example.multipledatathroughactivitypractice:id/container) for fragment PlaceholderFragment{b2cf4030 #0 id=0x7f050040}
06-17 07:59:03.020: E/AndroidRuntime(1216):     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2195)
06-17 07:59:03.020: E/AndroidRuntime(1216):     at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2245)
06-17 07:59:03.020: E/AndroidRuntime(1216):     at android.app.ActivityThread.access$800(ActivityThread.java:135)
06-17 07:59:03.020: E/AndroidRuntime(1216):     at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1196)
06-17 07:59:03.020: E/AndroidRuntime(1216):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
06-17 07:59:03.020: E/AndroidRuntime(1216):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:136)
06-17 07:59:03.020: E/AndroidRuntime(1216):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5017)
06-17 07:59:03.020: E/AndroidRuntime(1216):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
06-17 07:59:03.020: E/AndroidRuntime(1216):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
06-17 07:59:03.020: E/AndroidRuntime(1216):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:779)
06-17 07:59:03.020: E/AndroidRuntime(1216):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:595)
06-17 07:59:03.020: E/AndroidRuntime(1216):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
06-17 07:59:03.020: E/AndroidRuntime(1216): Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: No view found for id 0x7f050040 (com.example.multipledatathroughactivitypractice:id/container) for fragment PlaceholderFragment{b2cf4030 #0 id=0x7f050040}
06-17 07:59:03.020: E/AndroidRuntime(1216):     at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:919)
06-17 07:59:03.020: E/AndroidRuntime(1216):     at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:1104)
06-17 07:59:03.020: E/AndroidRuntime(1216):     at android.support.v4.app.BackStackRecord.run(BackStackRecord.java:682)
06-17 07:59:03.020: E/AndroidRuntime(1216):     at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.execPendingActions(FragmentManager.java:1467)
06-17 07:59:03.020: E/AndroidRuntime(1216):     at android.support.v4.app.FragmentActivity.onStart(FragmentActivity.java:570)
06-17 07:59:03.020: E/AndroidRuntime(1216):     at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnStart(Instrumentation.java:1171)
06-17 07:59:03.020: E/AndroidRuntime(1216):     at android.app.Activity.performStart(Activity.java:5241)
06-17 07:59:03.020: E/AndroidRuntime(1216):     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2168)
06-17 07:59:03.020: E/AndroidRuntime(1216):     ... 11 more
```

Comment: You have to decide which view to show, nobody can tell you. But guessing from the name, it's the wrong one. You do setContentView(R.layout.fragment_display_information); in your activity...

Comment: try this way .add(android.R.id.container, new PlaceholderFragment()).commit();

Comment: Remove  if (savedInstanceState == null) {
        getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction()
                .add(R.id.container, new PlaceholderFragment()).commit();
    }

Comment: Added the Logcat sorry about that @SimplePlan

Comment: actually no need to remove if block, since activity will store fragment state when its in background and when it comes to foreground it'll simply restore the state. If you remove this block, there will be 2 instance of fragment

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to remove this code

```
if (savedInstanceState == null) { getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction() .add(R.id.container, new PlaceholderFragment()).commit(); }
```

and change this

```
setContentView(R.layout.activity_display_information);
```

Comment: Omg thank you so much, this made it work! For future reference can you please explain to me what the code I removed actually does and why it was not working?

Comment: You shouldn't remove that block of code, otherwise you'll have multiple fragments when your activity goes background and comes back. savedInstance will have fragment instance already.

Comment: It doesnt work if I have the `if` statement in the code though

Comment: @bbesase if you want to used `Fragment` then add it to your activity by using `getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction()
                .add(android.R.id.container, new PlaceholderFragment()).commit();` and then put your all code in your `Fragment`. this'll add a `Fragment` to `android.R.id.container`

Comment: @bbesase but if you really dont want this `Fragment` Block then just remove it. so i suggested remove it.

Answer (score 0):

It seems that you are inflating wrong layout in activity on create.Try like below.

```
setContentView(R.layout.activity_display_information);
```